# Good way to template a class/struct combination

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

what's the most effective way to template a class that calls will need to call a templated struct. This is the classic ordered list problem with templating. My entire ordered list works as of now (when I simply change the types manually). However, I am not sure how to go about templating the pair of objects (the struct and the class).

So basically, here is how my code is structured:

```
struct Node {
    int* data;
    Node* next;
};

class OList {
    private:
        Node* start;
        int size;
    public:
        a bunch of manipulation functions
};
```

So, my desire is to simply template the struct, and then accept a parameter that will pass the template into the Node struct type. However, my first attempt, which was to do:

```
template<class T>
```

before the Node struct and change all the `ints*` to `T*` failed miserably. What might be a better approach in anybody's experience? Can anybody point me in the right direction or give me some good references for template basics? All I can find are specific questions, which doesn't give me a good background to how templating works.

UPDATE: My code works very well at this point. The only thing I still do not understand is how to return pointers of the Node struct in functions. For example, in a function that might be,

```
template <class T>
List<T>::Node<T>* List<T>pos(int val); //trying to return a pointer to the node at a specified spot
```

I get the following error: "Non-templated 'Node' used as template. note: use OList::template Node' to indicate that it is a template (???) error: need 'typename' before 'OList::Node' because 'OList is a dependent scope" What is the most efficient way to clear up these errors? Code works perfectly when this one function is commented out.

Comment: Please include the declarations of `Node` and `OList` after templatizing them.

Comment: "failed miserably" is not even close to an adequate description of a problem...Did you also make `OList` a template? Or just `Node`"?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good practice or possible but you could put the `Node` class inside the `OList` class and go from there?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates

Comment: I made both of them templates

Comment: I think I fixed the issue. I forgot to typedef Node<T>* start, and just did Node* start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename T>     // <----
struct Node {
    T* data;              // <----
    Node* next;
};

template <typename T>     // <----
class OList {
    private:
        Node<T>* start;   // <----
        int size;
    public:
        a bunch of manipulation functions
};
```

Alternatively...

```
template <typename T>
class OList {
    private:
        typedef ::Node<T> Node;  // <---- just do it once
        Node* start;
```

...or as suggested in BWG's comment, define `Node` directly in `OList`, so all the `<T>` aspect is implicit...

```
template <typename T>
class OList {
    private:
        struct Node { T* data; int size; };  // <----
        Node* start;
```

---

Example of out-of-line member function definition:

```
template <typename T>
class OList
{
    private:
        struct Node { T* data; };
        Node* f(Node*);
    public:
};

template <typename T>
typename OList<T>::Node* OList<T>::f(typename OList<T>::Node* p)   // see notes
{
    Node* p2 = p;    // can use Node as if inside class definition
    return p2;
}
```

Note the ugly line...

```
typename OList<T>::Node* OList<T>::f(typename OList<T>::Node* p)
```

...where `typename` is needed to indicate that `Node` names a type inside `QList<T>` (so it can do a bit more to make sure the function might makes sense even before it's instantiated for any specific type 'T'), and we need to continually mention both that `Node`'s inside `QList`'s scope, and that the specific instantiation of `QList` in which it's to be found is based on the template parameter `T`.  It all makes sense, but it's a bit pedantic.

---

As for how templates work in general, that's arguably "too broad" for answers on Stack Overflow, but FWIW perhaps the fastest way to jump-start some practical understanding of that (which will need some refinement afterwards), is by comparing them to macros.  Consider:

```
#define NODE(T)      \
struct Node ## T {   \
    T* data;         \
    Node ## T* next; \
};
```

With this, you can say `NODE(int)` or `NODE(float)` to generate `Node_int` and `Node_float` structures for those types.  With templates, you don't (normally) need to define each specialisation separately - it's done implicitly when used (*"parametric polymorphism"*)- so just start using them for variables ala `Node<int> my_node_for_ints`.

Comment: So I can put the entire struct withing the class definition for OList? That would make things much easier, since then I would only have to do template one of them instead of both

Comment: Also, in the functions below the declarations in the .h file, how do I specify type T? For example, I have a few functions that take inputs of the given class type and then perform functions on them that are specified in the class definition. See above for sample code as to what I'm tlaking about.

Comment: @Eric - "put the entire struct withing the class" - yes, certainly... it's better encapsulation that way if `Node` is not being used in the implementation of other (container) types....

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense since Node is only used in the context of the class definition. Thanks for all your help; I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Eric Re defining member functions after the class definition... I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: yep, that's basically what I ended up doing anyway. i just put the typename out front and it worked exactly as I desired it to. Didn't need the Node* as an input parameter (accepts an int) so no point in typenaming the Node* in the input as well.

Comment: @Eric I wrote my example before you'd got around to posting your code, so it doesn't match your one-int-parameter, but good to hear you've worked it out....  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* next;
};

template <typename T>
class OList {
    private:
        Node<T> start;
        int size;
    public:
};
```

?